# Can I prevent ctrl + shift + p system print dialog on windows in the browser?

Tags: javascript, printing, event-handling

I would like to use the key combination ctrl + shift + p to open a command palette similar to how one opens on https://vscode.dev. This appears to work fine in browsers on MacOS, however when I try to do the same on windows it will open a system print dialog.

I have tried to add an event listener for 'beforeprint' but I don't believe it is cancellable.

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeprint', (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I'm trying to prevent the print dialog in this handler for the keybind

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
   if (event.key === 'p' && event.shiftKey && (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey)) {
      // Prevent browser print dialog
      event.preventDefault();
      // Prevent dev tools command palette from opening
      event.stopPropagation();
      
      // Do logic here
   }
});
```

This handler works seems to work fine on MacOS safari and chrome but I cannot replicate the behavior on Windows where it opens the system print dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using/can use `jQuery`:

```js
$(document).bind("keyup keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80) {
    alert("Do what ever you want here.")
    return false; // Stops print  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*If you run it here, it won't work. Try running it on codepen or somewhere else.*

Comment: My problem was using `event.key = 'p'` instead of `event.keyCode = 80` for my handler. With that change I was able to successfully override the system print dialog. 

Note: I only needed the `'keydown'` event, I did not add anything to `'keyup'`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by switching my check for `event.key === 'p'` to `event.keyCode === 80`. I did not have any need for the `'beforePrint'` handler.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
   if (event.keyCode === 80 && event.shiftKey && (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey)) {
      // Prevent browser print dialog
      event.preventDefault();
      // Prevent dev tools command palette from opening
      event.stopPropagation();
      
      // Do logic here
   }
});
```